# How to add if statement to a LINQ query in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the the following query method:

```
internal List<Product> productInStockQuery(InStock inStock1)
{
    var inStock =
        from p in products
        where p.INStock == inStock1
        select p;

    return inStock.ToList<Product>();
}
```

I would like the method to do the following:

If `inStock1 == InStock.needToOrder` I would like it to search for both (something like): 
    `(instock1==InStock.needToOrder && instock1==InStock.False)`

How can I do that?

I would also like to know if it is possible to create a method that allows me to search all of my Product fields in one Method.

*EDITED SECTION*: (second question i had)
trying to explain myself better: my class has several fields and right now for each field i have a method like shown above i wanted to know if it is possible to create a special variable that will allow me to acces each field in Product without actually typing the fields name or getters like instead of p.price / p.productName i would just type p.VARIABLE and depending on this variable i will acces the wanted field / getter

if such option exists i would appreciate it if you could tell me what to search the web for.

p.s
thanks alot for all the quick responses i am checking them all out.

Comment: how is it possible to have both and condition true, it will hold one value at a time, BTW what is the definition of ``InStock`` ?

Comment: you can create variables within your query with the 'let' operator, but not sure what you are actually asking to be honest.

Comment: Question is not excactly clear. Is the question how to be able to return something that is not `List` just of `Product`, but could be also `List` of something else?

Comment: InStock is an enum which contains: false,true,needToOrder

i will search the 'let' operator now thanks 
trying to explain myself better: 
my class has several fields and right now for each field i have a method like shown above 
i wanted to know if it is possible to create a special variable that will allow me to acces each field in Product without actually typing the fields name or getters
like instead of p.price / p.productName 
i would just type p.VARIABLE and depending on this variable i will acces the wanted field / getter

Comment: @GalSheldon Add these explanations to your original post, please.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean using something like an Enum?

```
internal enum InStock
{
    NeedToOrder,
    NotInStock,
    InStock
}

internal class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InStock Stock { get; set; }
}
```

Then pass a collection to the method...

```
  internal static List<Product> ProductInStockQuery(List<Product> products)
        {

            var inStock =
                from p in products
                where p.Stock != InStock.NeedToOrder && p.Stock != InStock.NotInStock
                select p;

            return inStock.ToList();
        }
```

Create a list and pass it in...

```
        var prods = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Im in stock",
                Stock = InStock.InStock
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Im in stock too",
                Stock = InStock.InStock
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "Im not in stock",
                Stock = InStock.NotInStock
            },
            new Product
            {
                Name = "need to order me",
                Stock = InStock.NotInStock
            },
        };


        var products = ProductInStockQuery(prods);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compose queries based upon an input variable like so:

```
var inStock =
    from p in products
    select p;

if(inStock1 == InStock.needToOrder)
{
    inStock = (from p in inStock where p.INStock == InStock.needToOrder ||  instock1 == InStock.False select p);
}
else
{
    inStock = (from p in inStock where p.INStock == inStock1 select p);
}

return inStock.ToList<Product>();
```

Comment: it's the simplest method, but requires to add multiple conditions any time which makes your code ugly. I believe author is looking for a general solution for this problem

Comment: Your first statement is redundant. You are selecting all p from products without altering anything

Comment: Yeah - it's just posing an example.

Comment: Although - you'd need to do this, if you wanted to compose-on other criteria, etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use **WhereIf** LINQ extension method to make it more clear and reusable. Here is an example of extension

```
public static class MyLinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Boolean condition, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> predicate)
    {
        return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> WhereIf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Boolean condition, Func<T, Boolean> predicate)
    {
        return condition ? source.Where(predicate) : source;
    }
}
```

Below you can see an example how to use this approach

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new List<Int32>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var condition = false;                              // change it to see different outputs
        array
            .WhereIf<Int32>(condition, x => x % 2 == 0)     // predicate will be applied only if condition TRUE
            .WhereIf<Int32>(!condition, x => x % 3 == 0)    // predicate will be applied only if condition FALSE
            .ToList()                                       // don't call ToList() multiple times in the real world scenario
            .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));  

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
q = (from p in products);
if (inStock1 == InStock.NeedToOrder)
    q = q.Where(p => p.INStock == InStock.False || p.InStock == InStock.needToOrder);
else
    q = q.Where(p => p.INStock == inStock1);

return q.ToList();
```

Comment: `q` will throw an error, you need: - `q = (from p in products select p);` P.S - I am not the downvoter.

Comment: its also entirely redundant